# Inserting the iframe into react component

Tags: iframe, reactjs

I have a small problem. After requesting a data from a service I got an iframe code in response.

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/show?data..." width="540" height="450"></iframe>
```

I would like to pass this in as a props to my modal component and display it but when I simply `{this.props.iframe}` it in the render function it is obviously displaying it as a string.

**What is the best way to display it as html in react or using JSX?**

Comment: Consider to use https://github.com/svenanders/react-iframe

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use property [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), like this

```js
const Component = React.createClass({
  iframe: function () {
    return {
      __html: this.props.iframe
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.iframe() } />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const iframe = '<iframe src="https://www.example.com/show?data..." width="540" height="450"></iframe>'; 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component iframe={iframe} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

also, you can copy all attributes from the **string**(*based on the question, you get iframe as a string from a server*) which contains `<iframe>` tag and pass it to new `<iframe>` tag, like that

```js
/**
 * getAttrs
 * returns all attributes from TAG string
 * @return Object
 */
const getAttrs = (iframeTag) => {
  var doc = document.createElement('div');
  doc.innerHTML = iframeTag;

  const iframe = doc.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
  return [].slice
    .call(iframe.attributes)
    .reduce((attrs, element) => {
      attrs[element.name] = element.value;
      return attrs;
    }, {});
}

const Component = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <iframe {...getAttrs(this.props.iframe) } />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const iframe = '<iframe src="https://www.example.com/show?data..." width="540" height="450"></iframe>'; 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component iframe={iframe} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><div>
```

Comment: What are the downsides to using this like this? `Dangerously` sounds... well... dangerous

Comment: Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML only if you have good control over what you are "iframing", otherwise it will expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

Answer (score 62):

If you don't want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML then you can use the below mentioned solution

```
var Iframe = React.createClass({     
  render: function() {
    return(         
      <div>          
        <iframe src={this.props.src} height={this.props.height} width={this.props.width}/>         
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Iframe src="http://plnkr.co/" height="500" width="500"/>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

here live demo is available [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLORwtHB23KPCWPtnpWi?p=preview)

Comment: it is not that I don't want to use it I am not 100% sure how it can go wrong. Your solution is clean I would just required me to parse the string to extract the values.

Comment: as per my understand in React to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not a good practice and ya if you think my solution would be an answer then accept it

Comment: thanks for this code.. this is better than using dangersoulySetHtml

Comment: @Dhaval Patel this solution is good, however, based on the question, this does not solve the problem - **After requesting a data from a service I got an iframe code in response** - seems iframe is a string, how to render it in this case?

Comment: @AlexanderT.: can you please post some code what exactly you want to render

Comment: @Dhaval Patel for instance, I get this string from server when I do `http://server.com/a` - `<iframe src="http://x" width="200" height="200"></iframe>`, also I can get another result from `http://server.com/b` list so - `<iframe src="http://y" width="100" height="100"></iframe>`, or `<iframe src="http://z" width="20" height="20"></iframe>` - respose is always string, and I can't change response, how your solution will handle such case? My question related to base question *After requesting a data from a service I got an iframe code in response*.

Comment: @AlexanderT. Ohh simply you can parse the response and manipulate your response to find the iframe from it.

Comment: Please keep in mind this best practices as well: https://medium.com/@ebakhtarov/handling-of-iframes-in-react-f038be46ac24

Comment: Sems to depend on create-ceact-class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482477/5308983

Answer (score 22):

**With ES6 you can now do it like this**

Example Codepen URl to load

```
const iframe = '<iframe height="265" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" title="fx." src="//codepen.io/ycw/embed/JqwbQw/?height=265&theme-id=0&default-tab=js,result" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/ycw/pen/JqwbQw/">fx.</a> by ycw(<a href="https://codepen.io/ycw">@ycw</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</iframe>';
```

**A function component to load Iframe**

```
function Iframe(props) {
  return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html:  props.iframe?props.iframe:""}} />);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Iframe Demo</h1>
      <Iframe iframe={iframe} />,
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Edit on CodeSandbox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-iframe-demo-g3vst