# Easiest way to add html to a React component

Tags: html, reactjs

Say I have the following component in my web app:

```
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

  <div className="about">
  /* place html here. */ 
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm currently practicing my understanding of raw html/css.  So ideally, I want to be able to write up this about section somewhere else.  E.G., an `about.html` and an `about.css`, an `about.html` with some inline css, or a `<style>` tag.  Or most ideally, lower down in the same file that defines this component.

The idea is I want to separate my practicing of hmtl/css from the React specific / JSX code.

Is this possible?  and if so what is the least friction route assuming that this is not a very mission critical project and I'm fine with taking a less secure or more hacky approach?

Comment: This might be a duplicate question, is this what you're looking for? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973757/how-can-i-render-html-from-another-file-in-a-react-component

Comment: would this `about.html` be only some `div`s and html elements or would it be an entire html document with `head` and `body`?

Comment: if you want to practice `raw html`, then don't use react, that is not what it's for. setting `innerHTML` is an anti-pattern. the point of a react component is, it has the JSX that it translates to HTML, you can import stylesheets and use a number of ways to embed them - via loaders or css modules / inline. look at vue or whatver mvc framework hipsters like these days

Comment: @Sag1v it would be a bunch of tags and styles in side the div that the about component renders, yes..

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can declare a variable elsewhere or write a different component separate from this block and bring it in. But at the end of the day, you're still going to be writing JSX. You can still use `.css` to style your JSX the same as you would html, there's really no difference.