# how to import HTML file into React component and use it as a component?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to import an **HTML** file **into** a **React** component

[image]

**peft.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import perf from perf.html

class Index extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
         <iframe src="perf"></iframe>   /* like this */
         <iframe src="./perf"></iframe> /* or like this */
         /* or like any possible way */
      );
   }
}
export default Index;
```

so in my case, I need to import a local HTML file and use it in  
but I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users....\target.html
>   Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

any ideas? 
How to load an HTML file inside of a React Component?
How to add an appropriate loader to handle this file type?
Anything?

I find this solution as most logical:

```
var __html = require('./template.html');
var template = { __html: __html };

React.module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />
    );
  }
});
```

but I can not apply it because I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module parse failed: C:\Users\....\target.html Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. 
| <!DOCTYPE html> 
| <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; 
| <head><title>
```

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973757/how-can-i-render-html-from-another-file-in-a-react-component

Comment: Why not make it `peft.js` instead of  `.html` extension? Is there any reason?. You can also use this "const component(){ return(<div>hello World</div>)}"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can import or require the html file and use it in the src attribute,

```
var perf =require('./template.html');

class Index extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
         <iframe src={perf }></iframe>   /* like this */
      );
   }
}
export default Index;
```

Comment: But where are you using `IndexedDB` ??

Comment: I am curious to know the answer for this problem. I am running into the same error as mentioned in the post. The answer given above "<iframe src={perf }></iframe> " didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlText }} ></div>`

Comment: u still get Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!DOCTYPE html>
| <html lang="en">
| <head>

Comment: Works fine with `Create React App`, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 12):

Spent 2 hours on this.

**Two ways** to do the same below:

1. Method1 - `iframe` (part of page) goes to that html file (`chap3.htm`)
2. Method2 - `fetch` the contents of `chap3.htm` and set to state, state is added with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

---

**NOTE**

1. Html file is in `public` directory (`myapp\public\chap3.htm`).
2. May work from current directory too, but does not look like as a usual way to load static resource/html from current directory.

---

**Method 1**

```
import React from'react';
import'./App.css';

function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <iframe src="chap3.htm"></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

**Method 2**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState }from'react';
import'./App.css';

function App() {
  let[htmlFileString, setHtmlFileString] = useState();

  async function fetchHtml() {
    setHtmlFileString(await (await fetch(`chap3.htm`)).text());
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHtml();
  }, []);

  return(
    <div className="App">
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlFileString }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---