# How to import html file into react as string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have an HTML template as a separate file that I would like to import into my react application.  The intention will be replacing specific keywords and then sending it as the body in an email.

How can I import this html file into my react application?

I have tried `import htmlString from '../../../constants/EmailHTML.html';` as well as `var html = require('../../../constants/EmailHTML.html');` (which was suggested in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792942/how-to-import-html-file-into-react-component-and-use-it-as-a-component))

I get the following error for both attempts:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file.

Effectively this question boils down to:  How do I import a text file as a string in React?   This is an often-answered question and all the results seem to be to use an async loader -- something that shouldn't really need to happen given the file is in my src directory ready to go before build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require file as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752622/require-file-as-string)

Comment: Not really, as those rely on using the filesystem module from node.js and the use of a readFileSync.  Though, perhaps importing is simply a complicated process and I need to deal with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for create-react-app:

- [Install](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/installing-a-dependency) the raw-loader package `npm i --save raw-loader`
- Add a test HTML file you want read to src.  I added test.html.
- Add the lines below where you want to get the contents of the HTML file into a JavaScript string.  `html` will contain the string contents of the file.

Code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
var htmlModule = require('raw-loader!./test.html');
var html = htmlModule.default;
```

Comment: Create-React-App kind of hides the webpack stuff from you unless you 'eject' your project.

Comment: I've posted an answer for create-react-app.  It would have been good to mention it in the original question :-)