# Typescript error when trying to import an html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to import an HTML file to render it inside of a react component.

I'm getting the following typescript error:

```
Cannot find module './privacy_policy.html' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

What could I do to get rid of it (other then use `@ts-ignore`)?

Comment: create a jsx file, and return the html in a functional componenet

Comment: What do expect importing an html file to do, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider declaring a *.html module in a file named `custom.d.ts` in your project (at the same place where you defined your `tsconfig.json`).

For example, I've used this configuration on a web application (essentially Vanilla JS + TS for newer code) bundled with webpack, to handle import of types of file different from JS(x) or TS(x).

The alternative, as you said, is to use `@ts-ignore` approach when it's for a single specific need.

Note for this approach: in my case, the TypeScript transpilation is handled via webpack (with the `babel-loader`), and the imports as well are handled via webpack (via specific loaders, which for HTML is `html-loader`).

The `html-loader` lets you import a HTML file as it was a string in your TypeScript / JavaScript file.

Normally, if you use the ReactApp template, you should have the `html-loader` included in the build pipeline (which runs webpack behind the scene), so you should be able to use it.

Here is how it looks my `custom.d.ts` file:

```
/* 
 * Tells the IntelliSense to allow import of the following file extensions in TypeScript.
 * Current Webpack config for these files doesn't embed their content, but provides the file path inside the Webpack bundle.
 */

declare module "*.svg" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
declare module "*.png" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
declare module "*.html" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform your HTML code to JSX (or TSX if you are using Typescript). Check online, there are few tools that might help you !

Then you will be able to import your HTML (converted to JSX) into your script:

```
import PrivacyPolicy from 'privacy-policy.jsx'

return (
    <PrivacyPolicy />
)
```

Comment: Since this is an external file, generated by an external service I prefer to consume it as is. I'm rendering it on a page using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. It works fine, but I'd love to get rid of that ts error.

Comment: If the external service has web server, you could use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to add external HTML to your site

Comment: It's one of those privacy policy generators. All they give you on the free tier is an html snippet to copy. I have to serve it myself.

Comment: I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794851/11730250
Tell me if it works !