# React use static html page as start page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React app where the start page needs to be a static html page created by the art team. The problem is that I can't get the Router to redirect from "/" to the static page

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/welcome/index.html" />
```

because it passes everything through the React index page (due to the single page application logic). I have tried to make a component with the static page's code in, but I keep getting a lot of errors which I don't know how to fix, as the static page contains a lot of `<svg>` tags that I am not familiar with (I could not have created this static page's functionality by myself). Is there any way to do a redirect bypassing React's single page logic?

Comment: `react-router` only manages pages the React app is rendering, internally. If you need to redirect to an external URL then use Javascript to do so, e.g. something like `window.location.href = "...."`.

Comment: Or even use old school links in your JSX components like `<a href="http://example.com/mystaticpage.html">click here</a>`. You can keep the static page completely separate from the React project.

Comment: I don't need to get there from a link. I need to make it so that when a user types the address mysite.com/, he is immediately redirected to mysite.com/welcome/index.html

Comment: Take the value from user input. Then use window.location.href

Comment: @HimuraDaBattosuai I think he meant "typed in the browser's adress bar", not in the application itself.

Comment: @MyrtoPirli does that link answers your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792942/how-to-import-html-file-into-react-component-and-use-it-as-a-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Made "/" redirect to a component called Welcome:

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/Welcome" />
```

and inside the Welcome component I put

```
export default function Welcome(){
  window.location.href = '/welcome/index.html';

  return(
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```