# Include HTML content in page using React (translating from Angular)

Tags: html, angularjs, reactjs

Using AngularJS 1.x, I used to do code like this to include static HTML content on a page:

```
...
<body>

<!-- Banner -->
<ng-include src="'banner.html'"></ng-include>

<!-- Navigational thumb -->
<div>
<div>
<ng-include src="'navbar.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
...
```

I would like to know how to do that in React (where I'm a total beginner).

Comment: Does `ng-include` read `banner.html` from disk? Do you use webpack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I render HTML from another file in a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973757/how-can-i-render-html-from-another-file-in-a-react-component)

Comment: @Håken Lid. Yes, banner.html is read from disk. I do not use webpack.

Comment: React can't access your file system on its own. You can use a build tool such as webpack to load the file at bundle time.

Comment: I looked at the docs for ng-include. It seems that it fetches the resource with a http request at runtime. There's no react equivalent. It's possible to do, but you have to write your own implementation in javascript. It's more common to do this stuff at bundle time, using webpack `raw` loader. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: I see and completely understand that this issue has no direct equivalent in React. Anyone know how to dispose of this question properly? I looked at Oleg's link, but it doesn't inspire a solution for me, so I hesitate to mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

React use another way to render Html as Ang, you should create dump component to render some html and include it where you need.
https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html - also check it.