# How to add external motion graphic html to React like a component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, animation, next.js

I want to import animation html file to React project and I have followed this one: [How can I render HTML from another file in a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973757/how-can-i-render-html-from-another-file-in-a-react-component)

But it won't work as I expected, because it only render the html layout, not the animation in js file and images source from media folder

I have `index.html` + js files within media folder contain the images resource.
I'm new in React, please help.

Update: I just found that the html file has been imported, but the defined style on `header` cannot apply to the `body` tag.

Comment: Is iframe an option?

Comment: I have tried it, it have same issue when it does not apply the animation and the images source