# How to import an existing HTML and JS feature into ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I am working on a project in react and I am trying to implement an [interactive map](https://github.com/ferolz/mapa-mexico-html5/wiki).

But I have some problems while trying to implement it. I created a function that retrieves all the HTML of the map, the map is then displayed, but it doesn't work. I think I am not loading the JS files of the map correctly.

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.maphighlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/scripts.js"></script>
```

I am doing it in this way in the `return` of the component

Comment: If you have a specific problem, please post code here

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way to mix jquery with react. More about it, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react#:%7E:text=No.,deleting%20stuff%20into%2Ffrom%20them.)

Answer (score 0):

No Option available to join jquery code with react. but you can render HTML page in React Component. for more detail  [Visit Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973757/how-can-i-render-html-from-another-file-in-a-react-component)