# how to create page url preview in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a react page builder, I am displaying user-created pages using dangerous HTML now I want when the user clicks a button preview to open this page on a new window.

Here is my component to display user pages

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import api from "../utils/api";

function MyPages() {
  const [MyPagesList, setMyPagesList] = useState();

  const getMyPages = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get("/pages");
      setMyPagesList(response.data.data);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMyPages();
  }, []);

  return (
        <div className="all-mypages">
          <div className="all-mypages__cards">
            {MyPagesList && MyPagesList.map(function (data, id) {
                return (
                  <div  className="mypages-card" key={id}>
                    <a className="mypages-card__link">
                      <div className="mypages-card__content"
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data.attributes.html}}></div>
                    </a>
                    <button className="preview " onClick={()=>history.push(`/mypages/preview/${data.attributes.html}`)>Preview</button>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
  );
}

export default MyPages;
```

When user clicks preview button here is what I get

[image]

My solution is not working and I am out of ideas, what do I need to do to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried this rather than a button? `<a target="_blank" className="preview" href={() => history.push(\`mypages/preview/$data.attributes.html\`)}>Preview</a>`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are there errors? Do things not show? Have you checked the Network Tools to see if the request for "/pages" is getting made?

Comment: @HereticMonkey check updated qn, I have added a screen short

Comment: @srWebDev that does not matter if its a button or a URL  the result is the same, check new update on qn

Comment: Please show text as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: From a quick glance, it's doing exactly what you're telling it to: appending the raw HTML onto the end of the URL. I'm not sure what you want it to do.

Comment: @HereticMonkey is just a HTML I want to display on this page instead of being rendered in displayed on URL, I cant paste it here its big,

Comment: @HereticMonkey agreed its doing exactly what is supposed to do, now I am asking how can I display this HTML as page on click ?

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973757/how-can-i-render-html-from-another-file-in-a-react-component

Comment: @srWebDev its not the same , most of the answers there it seems like they want to display a HTML page inside another component, for me, I want to display this HTML as page in preview,

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct, because you are appending the html to /mypages/preview/. If you want the data.attributes.html ( which is the user html content ) to be displayed on a new page then:

- Create another React component which looks for this html content from <s>localStorage</s> redux
- When clicked on the preview button open a new page with url in react router pointing to this component
- This component on load will get the localStorage html content and pass it to its dangerouslySetInnerHtml and display it.

Comment: I had to use a global state management because if you want to open a react component in a new page, passing the html as a route parameter or storing it in localStorage is not a good idea. Also data is hardcoded because I didn't have time to setup a mock api server. Link to the solution https://github.com/paiameya/react-new-page-redirection @TheDeadMan