# Embed videos with iframe in React JSX

Tags: javascript, iframe, reactjs

Apologies for naive question, because clearly I'm missing something obvious.

My simple stateless iframe component:

```
const Video = ({ src }) => (
  <iframe
    allowFullScreen
    frameborder="0"
    height="315"
    src={src}
    width="560"
  />
);
export default Video;
```

which I use like so in a `Parent` stateless component:

```
import Video from 'Video';

const Parent = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlRxNSRA7Rg"/>
  </div>
);

export default Parent;
```

This seems to render properly, but the iframe is blank.

I suspect is something to do with the media event that React supports, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the src for iframe in such a way is considered dangerous due to XSS attacks. You will have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Read about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913737/inserting-the-iframe-into-react-component)