# How add raw html file to public folder in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I have an react application created using create-react-app.I have included a static html page in public.

I'm want to use that html in the same application using iframe.

The iframe with covid.html is not loading after the build.

-- Public

- covid.html

[image]

After the build the iframe url looks like this

```
<iframe src="/covid.html"/>
```

which is considering the html file as 'www.mydomain.com/covid'

How do i use the html file in the Iframe in public folder?

I use BrowserRouter.

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913737/inserting-the-iframe-into-react-component

Comment: @keikai No. the answer has iframe with external urls. In my case the html is in the same project folder.I need to load the html file as src

Comment: If the HTML is in your project file structure, why don't you simply `import` it as a normal react component?

Comment: @keikai the html internal has javascript functions and imports. If i import how do i display the html ?

Comment: Show the full code thx.

Comment: @keikai the html ?

Comment: I tried it in my app and it works for me. I made the `covid.html` in `public` directory. And I put `<iframe src="/covid.html"/>` in some react component. And it showed up. You might have some other problem.

Comment: @karianpour did you build it and check ? It works in the while running the app.After the build it doesnt

Comment: @anud33p , I tried also with build and in server. You might have some problem in the server or if you use `serviceworker` it might cause problem.