# use captive content in \public folder as an iframe source in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My react project has some areas where we want to use third-party tools (articulate storyline) which creates a HTML5 page (along with its media resources).  If we place that folder on our web server separate from the react project or point the iframe to a youtube URL all is fine.

If we place the folder in \public or \src,  how can we suppress react handling of the file or folder. What is happening is it recursively showing the react app instead of the wished for file.

```
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe
      width="560"
      height="315"
      src="../../Public/Buckconverter/story.html"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      loading="lazy"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```

I have reviewed:
[How add raw html file to public folder in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740956/how-add-raw-html-file-to-public-folder-in-create-react-app)

and

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system

Answer (score 0):

```js
src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Buckconverter/story.html`}
```

Comment: sorry, it is still retrieving a recursive copy of what seems like app.js with the default nave header and page content instead of the story.html

Comment: @phoenixAZ Add your `router` file to your question.

Comment: Function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/TrainingTopics" component={TrainingTopics} />
          <Route path="/Labs" component={Labs} />
          <Route path="/LabScenario/:id" component={LabScenario} />
          <Route path="/LabScenarioPallet/:id" component={LabScenarioPallet} />
          <Route path="/Tutorials/Buckconverter" component={Buckconveter} />
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to put it in Public was the right one top stop routing processing - I had a flaw in path   src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}