# Add an external html file with query strings in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an html file and it accepts few query strings

Html file also contains css and script included using script tag

ie we can call this html file as below

`external.html?param='something'`

i have to use this html in a react component and return as JSX.
currently i have done returning as an Iframe as below

```
const Component = () => {
    const iframeUrl = `external.html?param='something'`;
    return (
        <iframe
            {...props}
            src={iframeUrl}
        />
    )
}
```

but how can i do without using iframe or iframe with local html(should not download html from server all the time)?

Comment: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: contentOfHtml}} />`

Comment: Hi, would wrapping the plain html from that external url in a react component work? instead of an iframe?

Comment: @RamuN the html file is huge and there are css and script include using script tag

Comment: Why not convert the html file to a react component that takes props instead of query params?

Comment: @rayhatfield the html is huge and contains external script added using <script> tag

Comment: Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913737/inserting-the-iframe-into-react-component ?

Comment: That's what iframe is made for, I don't think you can convert an html document to a react component just like that.

Comment: @Mordechai it is ok i can use iframe. but the html is always same for iframe ,but it is not caching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just import an HTML document as a react component. Iframes are just for that.

To import a local html file as an iframe without constantly requesting a remote resource you should paste the file content into the iframe's `srcdoc` attribute which is an alternative to `src` for inline html.

Keep in mind though that the html will still be transmitted on a reload, just together with the rest of the app instead of in a separate request. For real caching you'll have to utilize the local storage mechanisms et al.

With this in place, you can then manipulate the query params:

```
// iframe inside a react ref
frameRef.current.contentWindow.location.href += 'myQueryParams'
```

You can also refresh the frame (it preserves the params):

```
frameRef.current.contentWindow.location.reload()
```

Comment: srcdoc seems not working.
For the clarity what i exactly need is i want to load `https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html` in in iframe (this viewer is hosted in my server) .but this html should not request remote html file 

i am setting iframe with the above url and passing below query param
file=blob:https://abc.abc.com/c7ac784c-0845-4fc0-b98d-73c66673ba6d#page=1&zoom=auto,-89,842

Comment: I missed the query string part in the question. Let me think...

Comment: Are the queries handled in the html at client side (using the History API) or server side? I assume the former

Comment: from client side.

Comment: @NIshamMahsin Updated my answer, let me know if it helps.