# Trouble with embedding a third party iframe with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

Here are the integration instructions I was given:

```
<div id="flipp-container"></div>

<script
  src="https://aq.flippenterprise.com/MERCHANT_ID/iframe.js"
  id="flipp-storefront-script"
></script>

<script>
  var flippContainer = document.querySelector("#flipp-container");

  var storefront = new Flipp.StoreFront({
    accessToken: "ACCESS_TOKEN",
    merchantId: "MERCHANT_ID",
    merchantNameIdentifier: "MERCHANT_NAME",
    locale: "en-US"
  )};

  storefront.renderStorefront(flippContainer);

</script>
```

I am not too sure how to create a React Wrapper around this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can try something similar to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913737/inserting-the-iframe-into-react-component

Comment: This npm package allows you to include iframes in React components. You may be able to adapt your code to work in this wrapper. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe

Comment: Thank you @EspressoBeans and @It'sNotMe! The source URL is an iframe that renders the library, not the iframe itself. I still need a way to pass the access token and other information to the iframe. And then the iframe library renders the iframe.