# iframe redirect to the src URL in next app

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, next.js

I trying build a website whit next.js,

Needs run a xml file in https://bot.deriv.com/ or https://www.binary.bot/bot.html?l=pt, is the same platform.

I try run one of this URLs in iframe tag, but when i run the next dev, the page are redirect to the src arg.

the code:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (<html>
    <body>
      <p> Teste </p>
      <iframe src='https://www.binary.bot/bot.html?l=pt'/>
    </body>
  </html>)
}
```

I don't know why is happening.

Note: i need copy this https://pletsch-bots-free.com.br/ if you have any idea how to do it, will help me a lot

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913737/inserting-the-iframe-into-react-component

Comment: Don't, if i render an iframe it's redirect me to the source URL... inside a react component have the same behavior.

Comment: Remove the `<html>` and `<body>` tags, those are set in [`_document`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) and should not be used in your pages.